# Postgres CLI queries not executing

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, terminal

I've installed postgresql on my ubuntu OS with the help of this tutorial
[Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2).

I followed the first few steps to the point where i need to create ROLES but my queries doesn't execute, not even any of the select queries, it simply just move to the next line without any errors.

This seems to work for me when trying to create a new role

```
createuser test_user
```

but it doesn't prompt me with these options after the user has been created

```
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) n
```

I can't change the privileges of these users because my queries doesn't get executed not do I get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

> but it doesn't prompt me with these options after the user has been
>   created

That's normal with a recent PostgreSQL client. Add the `--interactive` option to be prompted with the options like the older version used by your tutorial.

From the manpage:

> ```
>   --interactive
>        Prompt for the user name if none is specified on the command line, and also prompt for
>        whichever of the options -d/-D, -r/-R, -s/-S is not specified on the command line. (This
>        was the default behavior up to PostgreSQL 9.1.)
> ```

---

About the queries that don't execute:

> my queries doesn't execute, not even any of the select queries, it
>   simply just move to the next line without any errors

You problably forget to finish the queries with a semi-colon. Or, the query has an unbalanced simple or double quote, and the interpreter waits for you to close the quoted section.
Edit your question with an exact copy-paste of what you have displayed on `psql` if you need more help about this. The prompt in `psql` reveals what states it's in and what it's waiting for.

Comment: I ended up using phppgadmin because of of a deadline but will definitely make use of your info, thanks guy!